# Trying to select nav ul li ul li in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried many options, but this what I have so far and it doesnt work.

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').querySelectorAll('ul li').style.background = color;

document.getElementsByTagName("NAV").getElementsByTagName("UL").getElementsByTagName("LI").getElementsByTagName("UL").getElementsByTagName("LI").style.background = color;
```

my html

```
<nav>
    <ul id = "mainNav">
        <li><center>
            <img id = "logo" src = "https://31.media.tumblr.com/cfc2c43f7e34ec3fcb60405fa5d4f5a5/tumblr_n9nvpjtNNW1tgkx81o1_1280.png"></center>
        </li>
        <li id = "search">

            <form name = "searchField">
                <img src = "http://31.media.tumblr.com/7732f8901e9c94cb94aa5cff9e11b2ae/tumblr_n8zm5cD1SL1tgkx81o1_1280.png"><input name = "search" type = "text" placeHolder = "" id = "search">
            </form>

        </li>
        <li><a href ="#">
            <img src = "https://38.media.tumblr.com/f319cbdb3a9bd4041fd2c6056827794b/tumblr_n9lpsfYFOB1tgkx81o3_1280.png" alt = "img/home.png">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href ="#">
            <img src = "https://31.media.tumblr.com/1dc400960f59fca2f738ceab516d24f4/tumblr_n9lpsfYFOB1tgkx81o4_1280.png" alt = "img/info.png">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li id = "section"><a href ="#">
            <img src = "https://38.media.tumblr.com/11cb610a9c031eaf5bb8789cb9739717/tumblr_n9lpsfYFOB1tgkx81o1_1280.png"alt = "img/camera.png">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "/photography">San Francisco</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Lake Tahoe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id = "section"><a href ="#">
            <img src = "https://31.media.tumblr.com/bd112082d5c902750e78aa9d7dd817fc/tumblr_n9lpsfYFOB1tgkx81o5_1280.png"alt = "img/projects.png">PROJECTS</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "/projects#informative">Informative</a></li>
                <li><a href = "/projects#profile">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id = "section"><a href ="#">
            <img src = "https://33.media.tumblr.com/e9a7f9ae946bdf2950be96f27023bb78/tumblr_n9lpsfYFOB1tgkx81o2_1280.png"alt = "img/contact.png">CONTACT</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href = "http://www.twitter.com/skarchmit" target =" _blank">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href = "http://www.instagram.com/skarchmit" target =" _blank">Instagram</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:skarchit@gmail.com" target="_top">Email</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
            <nav>
                <ul id = "viewNav">
                    <a href = "#"><li> Some things here</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to select nav ul li ul li with javascript?

P.S. I havent learned jquery. So I want to do it with pure javascript.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I want to affect multiple navs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"how to select nav ul li ul li with javascript"

Do you mean this?

```
document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li > ul > li');
```

Note that you can remove the direct children condition `>` where it suits you.

Also note that `querySelectorAll` returns a collection (non-live [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) so you must iterate over it to manipulate every elements.

```
   var nestedLis = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li > ul > li'),
       i = 0,
       len = nestedLis.length;

   for (; i < len; i++) nestedLis[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Since most array functions can manipulate array-like objects, you can also apply `[].forEach` to the node list.

```
[].forEach.call(nestedLis, function (li) {
    //manipulate li
});
```

Comment: assuming the secondary `ul` is a direct child of the `li`, then yes.

Comment: It sort of worked. If i do x[i].innerHTML = "changed"; It works, but not the backgroundColor. I might have used !important somewhere where I shouldnt have. Looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

QuerySelectorAll return a NodeList of objects, even if there is only one.
So you need to give the element position in the NodeList like so

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li')[0]
```

For the first element.
If you need to go trough all the elements, you'll need a loop like so

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.background = color;
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, which does not have all the array methods.

Comment: You are right Elliot de Vries. I will correct my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
document.querySelectorAll('NAV ul li ul li')
```

Comment: Would would this work and what he tried not? This is currently in the Low Quality Posts queue, and I'm voting not to delete, but you should add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of including the jQuery solution..

```
$('nav ul li ul li')
```

or add a class to your sub menus like #myID and target

```
$('#myID li')
```